# changing images through ling click in android

Tags: android, xml, animation

i am making a flashlight app in which i am using using two images, one each for flashoff state and flashon state respectively.
i want to have animation such that these two images get toggled(image 1 apperas then image2 then again image 2..infinite times) when there is longclick..
that is iwant to show this in longclicklistner...
here is what i have done..
i am using this animation..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha android:duration="1000" android:repeatCount="infinite"            android:repeatMode="reverse" android:fromAlpha="0.3" android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

and

```
            @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tButton.startAnimation(flickon);   //tbutton is an image button
        return true;
    }
});
```

}

using this animation is happening but images are not switching..please help

Comment: **android:longClickable="true"** did you add this in your XML ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
 image.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);
```

use the above code to set an image to the image view and use a thread that can change contents in the UI bascially some thing like this

```
public void onLongClick(View v) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);
       }
    }).start();
}
```

You can loop over it for as many times as you want.